# Plot list as colored squares matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to plot an array of lists `xs` in the same vein as a heatmap. The difference is that the result has to be projected on an actual `ys` axis.

`xs = [[0, 100.0, 0, 100.0, 0, 100.0, 0, 100.0], [0, 100.0, 0, 100.0, 0, 100.0, 0, 100.0], ...]`

`ys = [0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  4.90000e-02 -4.00000e-03  4.30000e-02  2.00000e-02 -8.00000e-03 -1.58000e-01 ...]`

Each value of an `xs` list should be represented as a different colored square depending on itsvalue (light blue for 0 and dark blue for 100 for example). If two `xs` points have the same `ys`, the most recent value has to be plotted.

I am trying to plot the result on a matplotlib subplot that is using `ys` as y-axis. I have tried with a seaborn heatmap and the visual result was exactly what I wanted, but I did not manage to use `ys` as my y-axis.
[image: Plot result with seaborn heatmaps]

Edit : Here is an example of what I have and what I would like to get.

[image: Example]

What I'm using now is : `sns.heatmap(xs,cbar=False,ax=axs[col])` with `axs[col]` being the subplot where my "heatmap" is supposed to be drawn.

Comment: I don't understand your question personally. Can you show the desired result given the exact input list you are providing? You said you got pretty close using `sns.heatmap`. Please show the code you wrote, and explain how the result should be different.

Comment: Hope that my edit will help you visualize ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider using a `pandas` DataFrame, then you could take advantage of `drop_duplicates()` to keep only one of the row for each y-value. Then it's just a matter of calling `sns.heatmap()` on the filtered dataframe:

```py
ys = [150,150,151,152,153,153,154]
xs = np.random.choice([0,50,100], size=(len(ys),8))
df = pd.DataFrame(xs, index=ys)
df['ys'] = ys
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset='ys', keep='last').set_index('ys')
sns.heatmap(df2, cmap='Blues')
```

[image]